# Table of strings in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way of creating a table with each cell containing a string in C# ?

The closest thing I found is multidimensional arrays `string[,] names;`, but it seems like its length needs to be defined which is a problem to me.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
string[] namePost;
int[] numbPage;
string post="";
string newPost;
int i=0;
int j=0;

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => regex1.Match(line).Success))
            {
                newPost = regex1.Match(line).Groups[1].Value;
                if (String.Compare(newPost, post) == 0)
                {
                    j = j + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    namePost[i] = post;
                    numbPage[i] = j;
                    post = newPost;
                    j = 1;
                    i = i + 1;
                }    
            }
```

Each instance of the `for` writes the name of the new "post" in a cell of `namePost`. In the end, the `namePost` table stores the name of all the posts that are different from one another.

What is the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You have 2 separate single-dimensional arrays and you want their values to 'sync up'? Why not just make an object that stores both values and then keep an array / list of  that object?

Comment: Are you looking to enter each word of the post as a string in an array?  Not totally clear what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, all I want to do is add the `post` string to the `namePost` table. I want to store every `post` that is read and that is different from the one before.
How do you create an object that stores all those values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to store the posts, you can use the [List class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) from the [System.Collections.Generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
List<String> namePost = new List<String>();
```

Then, instead of `namePost[i] = post;`, use

```
namePost.Add(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx

Use this, no need to define length at all.

Useful guide and examples:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Cyril Durand I tend to agree with you in general. Though DataTables are very common and after my answer a very quick google search gives you billions of examples. So even if the above link will be broken it still contains the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a

```
var table = new List<List<string>>();
```

This would give you a dynamic 2D table of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all your unique posts. If you want the result as a list you can just do a

> .ToList ()

with the result.

```
static IEnumerable<string> AllPosts(Regex regex, string filePath)
{
  return File.ReadLines (filePath)
    .Where (line => regex.Match (line).Success)
    .Select (line => regex.Match (line).Groups [1].Value)
    .Distinct ();
}
```